# Add custom network locations in Windows

Tags: networking, nas, network-drive

Does anyone know how to add a custom location to the network locations in Windows 10/11?

I cannot not for the life of me remember how I added the root directory of my WD My Cloud network drive to the "Network locations" section within file explorer. I know it was a pain the first time I was able to get it working but I reinstalled Windows and cannot figure it out. I am able to add the shares are locations but I would like the root directory listed.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idfLP.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Right click the drive and go to properties. Go to the "Sharing" tab.

[image]

Click advanced sharing and tick "Share this folder"

[image]

Now on any other computer you can access the drive by typing in `\\ShareName` through the run menu.

You can also use the "Permissions" section to give the appropriate read/write privileges to users who access the drive.

Comment: Thank you, but not quite what I meant. I can already access the network drive using \\zcloud (name of the drive) but what I'd like to do is have that location saved under the network locations section of this pc. When adding a network location it needs to use one of the shares (\\zcloud\data) for example and I'd like to use the root directory

Comment: You could save it as a shortuct? If you right click the directory > send to > desktop shortcut. You can then drag that shortcut to wherever you like... such as your windows sidebar or quick access menu. Anywhere really. Is that what you mean? The only other thing i can think of is to map it to a network drive?

Comment: I cannot map it as a network drive as I would have to specify which share to use and I would like access to the root directory. Check out the screenshot to see what I mean. That is what it looked like before reinstalling Windows. I can add a shortcut to %appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts but it just isn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. Had to uninstall the device from printers and devices. Once uninstalled it was listed under the network section. Dragged the file folder to AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts and it is working once again as intended.

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.